# mysql обновление пустых значений

Tags: php, mysql, update

Задача, наверняка, тривиальная для большинства людей, но у меня затупки. Есть к примеру, таблица:

id | user | age | phone | email

Есть абстрактный парсер, который получает эти данные. При парсинге некоторых данных может не быть, например у нас после парсинга образовалась такая таблица (телефон - уникальный ключ, он будет обязательно):

1 | vasya | '' | 2128506 | ''

2 | ivan | 34 | 345678 | vanya@mailsrv.com

Задача состоит в том, что при следующем парсинге обновить ТОЛЬКО пустые значения ячеек, не затрагивая уже имеющиеся. Можно-ли это все сделать одним запросом, если да, то подскажите примерно как, с mysql общаюсь на "Вы".

Конечно можно предварительно делать SELECT по телефону, если поле есть, то смотреть какие поля не заполнены, и после этого уже делать UPDATE, но это не кошерно, и вдвое увеличит число запросов

Comment: Это вполне себе кошерно, или с вас за каждый лишний запрос к БД денег просят?

Comment: `update tab set email=coalesce(email,'new@email.value') ...` или то же самое в insert on duplicate key update, если заранее не известно есть запись или нет и надо ее или вставить или обновить

Comment: А почему бы не обновить все поля? Можно сделать уникальным ключом например email и вставлять/обновлять всю строку через INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html )

Comment: +coalesce - я сразу и не сообразил

Comment: Все поля не надо обновлять, т.к. в обновлении всякая бяка может затесаться, а актуальная и поправленная инфа будет в табличке.  Ладно, при использовании coalesce нужно чтобы пустые строки были в NULL или это совсем не обязательно?

Comment: @Crasher Обязательно. Coalesce возвращает первый NOT NULL аргумент - так что пустая строка или горсть пробелов вполне пригодны к возврату.